# What is use of Singleton Class in dowloading Image by using Volley when i could just Typecast ImageRequest object into Request in add method

Tags: android, android-volley

When dowloading Images using Volley it recommend in the documentation to use of singleton class. But i could just Typecast ImageRequest into Request while passing the argumennt in add() method . and it could just work same. so what is the use of using Singleton Class instead of using this.
here is code,

```
package com.example.myvolleyimage;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final String url = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3862601/pexels-photo-3862601.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260";

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(url,
                        new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
                            }
                        },0, 0,null,
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.i("Error","error IS " +error);
                            }
                        });

                requestQueue.add((Request)imageRequest);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, technically, but then you're not really queueing images and letting Volley handle those requests. Having a single queue has advantages in different scenarios. For instance:

- if you're loading a list of items with images, a single queue allows volley to handle priorities and give priority to the most recently requested images, limit the amount of images you download at once, etc.
- each queue instantiates other classes that create threads. If you have multiple queues at the same time you're probably using more memory than you need, maybe create more threads than needed and causing thread switching for each image.

Nothing prevents from using Volley as you do, but it is recommended to keep a single instance so adding requests to it is faster and more resource-efficient

Comment: So it's Better to use Singleton class even for StringRequest , right ?

Comment: In general, if you are going to download more than one image during the lifetime of your app, yes. The point is that if you're going to download several images, even if the Activity just shows a single image but the user will enter the same Activtiy multiple times, you will benefit from reusing the queue and allowing Volley to handle the requests in the most efficient way.